# Mat-table collapsable except for one row?

Tags: angular, mat-table

I want to create a table where rows can be collapsed or expanded, except for one row (the last one). What is the best way to achieve this?
I mean something like this:

Expanded:
[image]

Collapsed:

[image]

Comment: I think `mat-footer-row` will solve your issue, as you want to show total in the end https://stackblitz.com/angular/bnyoexvdgno?file=app%2Ftable-footer-row-example.ts

Comment: Will this prevent the footer row to be collapsed?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether it is applicable to you, however just give a try. You can delete rows from your array when you want to collapse:

```
onCollapse() {
    const itemsToDelete = this.dataSource.data.length - 1;    
    this.dataSource.data.splice(0, itemsToDelete);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataSource.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by small hack

add  below line if you are making entire row clickable.

`*ngIf="!lastRow" [@detailExpand`]

else add below in tag where you making row clickable

```
*ngIf="!lastRow" [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
```

For your reference you can use the [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uqbgb9)

Comment: Hi, these are expandible rows but I need expandible/collapsable table except one row